# Bookdown bs4_book - changing h3 color

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am trying to change the `h3` font color throughout my book. The default `bs4_book` comes with a `style.css` in the root directory that looks like:

```
p.caption {
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
p code {
  white-space: inherit;
}
pre {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
pre code {
  white-space: inherit;
}
```

To this, I have added:

```
h3 {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

However, this fails to change the color. When I inspect the element in Chrome, I see:

[image]

The `h3` selector as defined in the `bs_4` theme CSS is not being over read by the `style.css` in the root directory of my Bookdown project. I am specifying in my `_output.yml` file that the `style.css` should be used.

Any idea how I can change the `h3` font color in my Bookdown `bs_4` book?

Comment: I created a `bs4_book` to try to help, but when I tried what did not work for you, it worked for me. Are you using a theme, other than what is automatically added when you create this type of `bookdown` output?